# Populate select box with array of object without form binding in laravel 5

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I want to populate select box which will have an array of objects.

Here's the array:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[208]
      public 'tag_identifier' => string 'jewellery' (length=9)
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[207]
      public 'tag_identifier' => string 'jewellery-rings' (length=15)
      public 'id' => string '3' (length=1)
```

What I am trying to achieve is that I want to update the products tags part from the edit form and while doing so, I want that whatever tags was inserted while adding the product should be highlighted.

Here's the controller method

```
public function edit( $id ) {
    if(\Auth::guest()) {
        return redirect('/admin');
    }

    $arr = [
        'products.id AS product_id', 'products.name AS product_name', 'products.category_id AS cat_id', 'products.description AS product_description', 'products.quantity AS product_quantity', 'products.rate AS product_rate', 'products.discount_rate AS product_discount_rate', 'products.display AS product_display', 'products.approval AS product_approval',

        'categories.id AS category_id', 'categories.name AS category_name'
    ];

    $product = \DB::table('products')
                ->join('categories', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->where('products.id', '=', $id)
                ->select($arr)
                ->first();

    if ( $product ) {
        $category = Category::lists('name', 'id');
        $tag_lists = \DB::table('product_tag')
                    ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'product_tag.product_id')
                    ->join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'product_tag.tag_id')
                    ->where('product_tag.product_id', '=', $id)
                    ->select('tags.name AS tag_identifier', 'tags.id')
                    ->get();

        $tags = Tag::lists('name', 'id');
        return view('products.edit')
                ->with('product', $product)
                ->with('category', $category)
                ->with('tag_lists', $tag_lists)
                ->with('tags', $tags);
    }
    \Session::flash('no_product', 'Sorry! The product that you are looking for could not be found');
    return \Redirect::back();
}
```

And in my views:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('tag_lists', 'Tags:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('tag_lists[]', $tags, [$tag_lists], ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'multiple']) !!}
</div>
```

`$tags` is used when there are no products having tags, that means it will show all the tags and vice-versa even when the tags are selected.

Kindly help me. Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**: After [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765500/populate-select-box-with-array-of-object-without-form-binding-in-laravel-5/29765543#29765543) answer, here's the array that I have got and it didn't helped me out.

```
array (size=2)
  1 => null
  3 => null
```

**UPDATE 2**:
There was a typo in UPDATE 1 and hence the result. Here's what I get after editing the typo..

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select `name` as `tag_identifier`, `id` from `product_tag` inner join `products` on `products`.`id` = `product_tag`.`product_id` inner join `tags` on `tags`.`id` = `product_tag`.`tag_id` where `product_tag`.`product_id` = 7)
```

**P.S.**: All the values are coming from the database. I am at a learning stage and that is why I have not used form model binding, reason, I want to go step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Tag::lists('name', 'id')` you are already doing it the easiest way. Now you have to apply the same to the query for `$tag_lists`. This should work:

```
$tag_lists = \DB::table('product_tag')
                ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'product_tag.product_id')
                ->join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'product_tag.tag_id')
                ->where('product_tag.product_id', '=', $id)
                ->select('tags.name AS tag_identifier', 'tags.id AS tag_id')
                ->lists('tag_identifier', 'tag_id');
```

Comment: Have a look at the updated question after your answer.

Comment: Kind of saw that coming... `lists` ignores the specified table and only `name` is ambiguous. Try my updated answer please.

Comment: Nope, when I use `var_dump( $tag_lists )` in my view just above the select drop down, I get the following: `array (size=1) '' => string 'jewellery-rings' (length=15)` and nothing gets selected in the select box.

Comment: There is a typo in your answer, instead of `tags_id` in the `lists()` method, it should be `tag_id`.